# Cycles - How can I make a sphere see through?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, transparency

How can I make a sphere see through like this:

https://sketchfab.com/models/f38fd38470c3496cb7a9f5a76fae41a1

I tried the normals trick (flip the normals so they face toward the inside of the sphere) and I tried to use the transparent shader (connected node to surface input), but neither worked.
Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with screenshots of what you want and what you have along with link to a model and some explanation of what is "normal map trick" and "transparent"?

Comment: also it might be worth mentioning whether blender internal or cycles

Comment: @MrZak it is clear. "normal map trick" means flipping the normals so they face towards the inside of the sphere, and "transparent" means using the transparent shader node for the surface material. a simple edit might be useful though. I will edit to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @MattTheWaffleCat that is very clear it is Cycles. It is in the title.

Comment: @Tooniis I'm glad it's clear for you, it wasn't clear for me as normal map is not the same as normals vectors

Comment: @Tooniis oops my bad! I didn't see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking for front face culling. I have made the material in cycles since you didn't specify which engine you are using. The sphere contains a blue cube and the front faces of the sphere are not rendered. If it appears black you need to set up a shadow-less light or place lights on the inside of the sphere.

The setup:
[image: Setup]

Comment: Note that this could also be done with render layers (and would probably look better too). This is just the material based solution.